# Help finding the limit of a sequence

Tags: calculus

I can see that the sequence converges to the number 2, but can't find a way to prove it.
$$
a_n = \sqrt[n]{4^2+2^n}.
$$ 
Thanks is advance.

Comment: $\large a_{n} \sim 2^{n/n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sqrt[n]{2^n}\le\sqrt[n]{16+2^n}\stackrel{\text{For}\;n\ge 4}\le\sqrt[n]{2\cdot 2^n}\;\ldots\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Hit: Use the Squeeze Theorem to get the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$a_n = (a^n + b)^{1/n}$
for any reals
$a > 1$ and $b > 0$.

$a_n = a(1 + b/a^n)^{1/n}$,
so
$\frac{a_n}{a} = (1 + b/a^n)^{1/n}
$.

Let
$\frac{a_n}{a}
= 1+c_n$,
so $c_n > 0$.
Since
$1+c_n = (1 + b/a^n)^{1/n}$,
$1 + b/a^n
= (1+c_n)^n
\ge 1+n c_n$
by Bernoulli's inequality.

Therefore
$\frac{b}{a^n} 
\ge n c_n
$
or
$c_n \le \frac{b}{na^n}$,
so $c_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Therefore
$\lim_{n \to \infty}
\frac{a_n}{a}
= 1$,
or,
$\lim_{n \to \infty}
(a^n + b)^{1/n}
=a$.

This also shows that
$(a^n + b)^{1/n}
\le a+\frac{b}{na^{n-1}}
$.

As a special case,
if $a = 1$,
$(1 + b)^{1/n}
\le 1+\frac{b}{n}
$.